# Load test against Android native application?

Tags: android, performance, load-testing

I have created one android app. I would like to make load testing to android app. But I don't have any idea about how to perform load testing.
My requirement is 3 devices testing my app simultaneously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is not for suggestions but about technical solutions. What have you tried? Where is the problem? What is your code used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can achieve this using JUnit Parallel test with selendroid

download ParallelTest folder from github https://github.com/gworksmobi/Grace

**Reference :** https://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/parallel-junit.html (this link is for selenium I am just modified to selendroid)

**Steps:**

1. Download folder from github
2. Add supporting selendroid jar to eclipse (http://selendroid.io/setup.html)
3. Create project.
4. Create the exact ditto class into your project as per github download folder
5. Now make the changes as per your application in JUnitParallel.java

**Description of class :**

JUnitParallel.java -> have business logic of testing

Parallelized.java  -> provide multi thread support

Comment: Just linking to your own stuff is [not a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). A good answer that involves an off-site resource includes the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and references the following: _What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?_ See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Comment: is it enough now? suppose not means I will do it again

Answer (score 1):

If your application communicates with backend server you can simulate network traffic coming from hundreds of applications using i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) by following next simple steps:

1. Record your application traffic (one or several scenarios) using [JMeter's built-in proxy server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   - disable cellular data on device and enable WiFi
   - make sure that host running JMeter and mobile device are on same network/subnet
   - start JMeter's proxy server
   - configure your mobile device to use JMeter as a proxy
   - click all buttons, touch actions, etc.
2. [Add virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
3. Run the test

If your application connects with the backend over HTTPS you may use 3rd-party tool like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) to set up SSL proxy. You will also need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` which is being generated in JMeter's /bin folder when you start proxy server. The easiest way to install it on the device is to send it by email.

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for more detailed instructions.

If you application doesn't use backend - it doesn't make sense to load test it at all.